# Cannot connect to the internet after assigning Host-Only Adapter on Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I've setup Ubuntu Server 22.04 on Oracle's VM Virtual Box Manager on a Laptop running Windows 10. I've selected the "Host-only Adapter" since I need a static IP, and the previous Bridged Adapter used to keep changing IPs each time my phone's hotspot was turned off and on. But now, the VMs have no internet access. I've added NAT as a second adapter, but that hasn't helped in any way. Am I missing something? How do I get this right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you could try to use iwd to connect.

Comment: For situations like this, the "Bridged Adapter" must be "Adapter 1" and the "Host-only Adapter" needs to be "Adapter 2". NAT will give you nothing. Be sure that the Host-only adapter is set to the adapter you created and you have "Allow All" for the Promiscuous Mode plus the "Cable Connected" option is checked. From there, everything should work. This is generally what I do for my VirtualBox VMs on notebooks that are used to deliver demos at various locations.

Comment: @matigo your directions saved the day

Answer (score 1):

With the help of **Bridged Networking** you can fix this issue. VirtualBox uses a device driver called **net filter** on the host system. It used to transfer data from physical network and inject into it. This means it acts as a bridge between the host and the VM.

### Follow the steps to configure bridge network for an existing virtual machine in virtual box:

1. Right click on the Virtual Machine from the Oracle VM VirtualBox
   Manager & Click on Settings
2. On the **Network tab**,

   - Click on Adapter 3
   - Check Enable **Network Adapter** and select **Attached to :
     Bridged Adapter**
   - Click OK to save the changes.

Comment: Thanks ajith. It helped me save a lot of time

Comment: I've done just as you've said, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Bridged Networking isn't the correct solution.  Depending on the network you're on, your whole machine could lose internet connection.  You want to have NAT setup so that you get internet connection and Host-Only so that you can SSH into you VM is needed or SFTP files to and from.  The above diagram shows only one network interface card A.K.A. NIC, enp0s3 (Host-Only) and not enp0s8 (which would in this case be the NAT connection).  Norman should activate the other NIC by editing the config file located at /etc/netplan/. Ubuntu has a bunch of examples here: https://netplan.io/examples

Answer (score 0):

### Connect to the internet an Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM guest on virtualbox 7

it should work for Ubuntu desktop too

I just paste here the reply of matigo on the original question at top,
because that is the combination that worked for my Virtualbox 7 environment installed on a Windows 10 PC connected to the internet through its WiFi adapter

For situations like these

- the "Bridged Adapter" must be "Adapter 1"
- "Host-only Adapter" needs to be "Adapter 2".
- Be sure that the Host-only adapter is set to the adapter 1 and that in the adapter 1 you have "Allow All" for the Promiscuous Mode plus the "Cable Connected" option is checked.

From there, everything begun to work fine

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing one config in netplan.
I was facing same issue in ubuntu22 but I configured netplan using below commands and it worked.

Step-1: `sudo vim /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

Step-2: Apply the above updated **netplan** using below command-

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Step-3: Now check the command "`ip a`" or "`ifconfig`" you will get ip in enpos8 interface as mentioned in below snapshot-
[image]

Step-4: Check the internet connectivity, it should work now as it is now working for me and also I'm able to do ssh using putty.

```
ping google.com
ssh 192.168.56.101
```